# Android: How to update application shortcut icon with a new items count programmatically

Tags: android, shortcut

I wanted to show the numbers in a application shortcut icon(without developing the widget), i would like to know how that number can be updated programmatically whenever i receive a service notification saying "n" new items added to the user. I am able to show the notification message whenever i get new items, I want to add this items count to the application shortcut icon(some thing similar to showing the new message count in the messages shortcut).

Thanks
Praneeth

Answer (score 1):

Use `Notification.Builder` class and set the number of the notifications using `setNumber(int number)` member function.

Comment: Thanks Alexander, my api version is 7, but Notification.Builder is available since 11.

Answer (score 0):

I know you don't want to use Widgets but I'm pretty sure the existing message count is based on a Widget.

Here's an example of how to get one up and running - [Widget Tutorial](http://amimetic.co.uk/?p=180)

Comment: The count am getting from a Service, in which i am getting the count and showing the notification using notification manager.